# How to get executable code from a cell in r

Tags: r

I have a data frame where in some cells I have written R code with the intention of being able to call it and use it as executable code, but I cannot find a way to do it when I indicate the cell, the result is a text string and R does not recognize it as code. How can I do it?

I put a small example, without putting the whole table:

This is the value of the cell:

```
> Mod_Adje$Filtros[1]

[1] "T1$PeA[j] >= 80 & T1$PeIR[j] >= 50 "
```

This is the function where i would like to execute the cell value:

```
for (j in 1:length(T1$Num)) {
   if (Modelo_Adje$Filtros[1])
    T1$AdjetCom [j] <- “Result1”
   else
    T1$AdjetCom [j] <- “Result2”
 }
```

Comment: You may need to evali.e. `eval(parse(text = Modelo_Adje$Filtros[1]))`

Comment: @akrun: Thanks, I finally figured it out